# Bind TreeViewItem.IsEnabled to ViewModel property for each TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeviewitem

I have a ViewModel which contains an observable collection of items called `AllNodesAndEntries`. Each item has a boolean property `IsEnabled`. Now I want to show the items in a TreeView and bind the `IsEnabled` property of each TreeViewItem to the `IsEnabled` property of its underlying item of the ViewModel. **How do I do that?**

Here is my TreeView. There are two different types of items (`Node` and `Entry`), so I have one hierarchical and one normal data template.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllNodesAndEntries}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entry}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}""/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <!-- How do I bind to TreeViewItem.IsEnabled to IsEnabled? -->
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

It seems I cannot do it inside `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`, because there I can only define setters. But setters don't allow binding the value...

Comment: setters do allow binding the value... how do you write bindings?

Comment: Okay, I thought that allowed syntax is only that which pops up while typing. And when I typed `Value=""` it only showed me `True` and `False`. Lesson learned, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setter to bind the "IsEnabled" property to your "IsEnabled" item property   of each TreeViewItem.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
    </Style>
 </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```